# Help with casio fx-9860G

Tags: basic, calculator

I need help writing custom functions for my casio fx-9860g

I have done this before in my Texas Calc but Im not sure there is a way to it with casio calculators... say, for instance, I want to write a simple function like so:

```
public int triple(int x)
{
return 3x;
}
```

I understand this is quite a simple function but I want a way to store some formulas so I can quickly calculate stuff without having to rewrite the formulas all over again.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casio basic doesn't have 'functions' like you want. For simple functions you use copy/paste, rather than abstract using functions. (This redundancy is better than you'd think)

For larger sub-routines you can write those as a program file and call them. See the *prog* and *return* commands in the manual.

```
File: "MySub"
----------------------
Y <- X * 3
return

File "MyProgram"
----------------------
X <- 5
Prog "MySub"
```